# Can i add SVG image in ImageView?

Tags: svg, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I have an imageView : `width=200 ,height=150` ,when i upload a big image (.jpg)  for example image :1200*500 pixels and i minus the width ad height of imageView ,the image lose his quality ,it will be not clear ,can i find a way to  add .svg or vector image in imageView ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an option by using [Transcoder API](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html) of [batik library project](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) from apache and convert the resultant BufferedImage to a JavaFX Image.

**Edit:**

Transcoder API provide classes to convert SVG document to PNG,JPG,TIFF,we can use this sample of code to create a JPEG image from SVG path,

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;

public class SaveAsJPEG {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a JPEG transcoder
        JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();

        // Set the transcoding hints.
        t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
                   new Float(.8));

        // Create the transcoder input.
        String svgURI = new File("C:\Users\Blue\Downloads\icon8_smile.svg").toURL().toString();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

        // Create the transcoder output.
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("icon8_smile.jpg");
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

        // Save the image.
        t.transcode(input, output);

        // Flush and close the stream.
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

By this way we can transform an SVG vector image to other image based on pixels.
Other option we can add it to our code ,for help us to define the size of output image  :

```
t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(250));
```

This line of code help us to define the size of image according to size of ImageView and we can make some changes like this :

```
t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, imageView.getFitWidth();
```

Comment: please would you concider sharing your solution

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb I tried to provide a full answer to my problem,rather than old answer which contains only the tool.There many solutions using this API like this solution https://gist.github.com/ComFreek/b0684ac324c815232556, thank you for your attention.